# How can I create a .desktop file [Desktop Entry] that executes a command in the current directory?

Tags: linux, debian, shortcut, desktop

I want to create a `.desktop` file that runs a specific command in the directory where the file is. This is what I have:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=MyApp
Exec=bash -c 'cd $0 && node index.js; read' $PWD
Icon=obconf
Terminal=true
Categories=Utility
```

Basically, I want to execute `node index.js` in the directory where the `.desktop` file is. As it is now, the pwd is always the home of the user (even if I'm deeper in the hierarchy). How can I make it so the command is launched in the directory where the `.desktop` file is ?

This is on a Raspberry Pi 5, Debian (bookworm).

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a variable that contains the file that was clicked on? Use `$(dirname "$filename")` replacing `$filename` with that variable.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: I wouldn't say this is a question about configuring Linux. It might be a one liner program but it is still a program. I just wanted to provide context. The question could be reworded as: how does one pass $PWD to a command executed with bash -c.

Comment: You are passing PWD. What you don't understand is that PWD doesn't change in the GUI, it simply inherits the PWD from when it was started, which is usually the home directory. You want the directory of the file you clicked on, not PWD.

Comment: So like I said, it depends on how your desktop manager passes the filename when you click on a desktop entry.

Comment: If you add `echo $0` to the command, do you see the current directory?

Comment: Even when you do it in the terminal? I doubt that very much.

Comment: What desktop manager are you using?

Comment: Just to be clear, when I run the command in a Terminal, it works. It stops working when it is in the context of the `.desktop` file.

Comment: You said "If I run this same command in a Terminal, the problem is also present." That's what I was disputing.

Comment: This is on a Raspberry Pi 5. I believe the desktop manager is called OpenBox (a modified version of LXDE).

Comment: As I told you, the desktop manager doesn't change working directories as you navigate. You need to get the directory from the filename.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'm sorry. I gave you bad info earlier. Now, how would I fetch the directory from the filename? In this context, isn't there a way to know where I am?

Comment: OpenBox is a window manager. Desktop managers are GNOME, KDE, or XFCE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Barmar mentionned in the comments, the GUI does not change the current working directory. However, I just found in this [nice guide](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/desktop-entry-files) that you can retrieve the path to the `.desktop` files by using `%k`. Hence, this works:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=MyApp
Exec=bash -c 'cd %k && node index.js; read'
Icon=obconf
Terminal=true
Categories=Utility
```

This basically tells Node.js to launch the `index.js` file in the directory where the `.desktop` file is located.

Thanks Barmar for your help.

Cheers!